# React.js / Leaflet -- Run useEffect on Mount only in DevServer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, use-effect

i'm running into the behavior, that i **must** run the useEffect Hook only once in react.
the reason is mainly because i have to init a leaflet.js map which must not happen more than once.

but whenever i change something in the components jsx, the "Hot Reload" feature of the DevServer seems to ignore useEffects 2nd argument `[]` and re-run it anyway, although the state of `coachmap` persists. This behavior throws an error:  `map is already initialised` which can only be fixed by reloading the browser tab.

Do you have any Idea how I can prevent react to re-initialise leaflet?

I've already tried to check if `typeof coachmap == 'undefined'` which strangely still re-initialises the map.

Here is my Component Code:

```js
import * as L from "leaflet/dist/leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function CoachMap() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof coachmap == "undefined") {
      // Initialise Leaflet.js Map
      const coachmap = L.map("coach-map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto my-4 ab">
      <div id="coach-map"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CoachMap;
```

Comment: Have you considered using [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/)?

Comment: Is component.jsx the parent component of CoachMap.jsx ?

Comment: I've actually tried using react-leaflet but gave up after it just didn't want to render. so i'm using vanilla leaflet.js right now. It actually works if it wouldn't re-execute on every component change. @SethLutske

Comment: CoachMap.jsx is directly mounted onto App.js @ZaidMakani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your component is called in App.js directly, why don't you wrap the component using React.memo. (This will prevent unnecessary re renders)

```
export default React.memo(CoachMap);
```

Don't forget to import 'React'

`import React, {useEffect} from "react"`

you could also replace useEffect with useMemo since you intend to memoize the value and not actually fire side effects.

```
const coachmap = React.useMemo(()=>{
  return L.map("coach-map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
}, []);
```

Comment: Nice one! I haven't thought of useMemo before. Unfortunately, the useMemo Hook runs too early tho o.O || div#coach-map has to exist before running the hook. And that's where the fun begins. @ZaidMakani

Comment: In that case why don't you try a combination of useMemo and useEffect. Set a flag on component mount and inside useMemo check for the flag prior to initialization.
You can add that flag as a dependency to use memo.

This will ensure that useMemo initialses the map after component has mounted.

Also don't forget React.memo at component level (its not the same as useMemo)

Comment: Okay. I've split the Map logic into a sub-component and exported it with memo() . This way useEffect won't trigger on LiveReload anymore. It's still strange tho'. The compiled Project doesn't have such behavior. The re-computation only happens when using a DevServer via `npm run dev`